# jQuery Drop Down Menu expand issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have Drop Down Menu which looks like that: http://jsbin.com/akidiw/2/edit

Click on "First" then next on "Second" and next on "Third" and you'll see the problem. I know it's all because of that part

```
 $("span.toggle").click(function() {
 $(this).addClass('expanded');
 $(this).next().toggle(1000);

 $(this).parent().parent().find('.expanded').not(this).each(function(){
   $(this).next().toggle(1000);
 });
 });
```

I want when you have expanded one object and you click on second, the first one is closing. Please help

Comment: Couldn't find the second option to click on. Could you make this in english for the sake of the demonstration here?

Comment: You mean all items in menu in english?

Comment: just the one you need us to click on would do. I couldn't find the "Uczyszczanie skóry", either because it's not there or the language was confusing

Comment: Oh it was a typo but now look, click "First" then "Second" and then "Third" :) http://jsbin.com/akidiw/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

You never remove the "expanded" class from items you close.

on the "click" event, iterate over the items that have "expanded" and remove that class.